# How can I randomize a single mysql column?

Tags: mysql, random

I have a database that consists of a string and a numeric probability (there are other columns but they are not relevant to the question). A simplified schema is

```
+-----------------------+----------------------+
| gopair                | P_high               |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
| GO:0000398_GO:0030540 |    0.275997567007171 |
| GO:0015198_GO:0016846 | 5.24489289777325e-06 |
| GO:0034649_GO:0072141 |  0.00338367340340417 |
| GO:0004303_GO:0031053 |    0.110417921058026 |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

In my work, I run a script that queries the database for the values associated with specific GO pairs. I need to demonstrate that my results are different to those obtained randomly. So, one of the tests I want to run is to shuffle the `P_high` column and then run my script and analyze the results.

I have tried to shuffle the input file and reload the database but this is complicated because the input file in question is a 7GB text file which is kind of hard to deal with on a machine that only has 3GB RAM.

So, is there a way I can randomize a specific column in my database while keeping the rest static?

Caveats:

- the table in question is LARGE (60,164,966 rows).
- I do not need rigorous mathematical randomness
- I need to keep the same frequencies. If *N* pairs have a probability of *P* in the real database, I need *N* pairs to have a probability of *P* in the random one.
- I need the solution to be persistent. My script could query the database for same pair multiple times, so simply selecting a random pair is not good enough.
- I will need to do all this repeatedly so scriptable (preferably Perl) solutions are preferred.
- I am running mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1, on an Ubuntu server.

Comment: `SELECT gopair, RAND() AS P_high FROM mytable`?

Comment: @SirRufo that won't work. I need the result to be persistent and to reflect the structure of the original database. So, if 154 gopairs have a probability of 0.005 in the original DB, then in the random DB I need 154 gopairs to have a prob of 0.005 as well. If I understand your solution correctly, it will simply choose a random value from the P_high column each time it is run, correct?

Comment: No, it'll just return a random value *as* the P_high column.  The value returned in Rufo's case has nothing to do with values existing in the database.

Comment: @Crontab, yeah, I just looked up the rand() function, not what I need at all. Good thing to know though :).

Answer (score 1):

What does the primary key for this table look like? If you're using an integer surrogate key you can: [assuming 4-byte ints]

1. Dump a listing of all keys. `$list[]` [240MB give-or take]
2. Duplicate the list. `$shuf[]` [another 240MB +/-]
3. Shuffle the duplicate list. [the shuffle function might return a copy, in which case skip #2]
4. Add another column to your table [ie: `shuffle_key`] with no index for the time being.
5. I am not terribly familiar with Perl syntax, but it's similar to PHP so:

   ```
   $cnt = count($list);
   for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++) {
       $query = sprintf(
           'UPDATE table SET shuffle_key = %d WHERE primary_key = %d',
           $shuf[$i], $list[$i] );
       $dbh->doQuery($query);
   }
   ```
6. Create a UNIQUE index on the new column.
7. Now you can self-join the table on the primary key and the shuffled key and use the gopair from one side and the P_high from the other.

   ```
   SELECT t1.gopair, t2.P_high
   FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2
     ON t1.primary_key = t2.shuffle_key
   ```

The amount of memory this should require will be roughly 2x the size of your primary key * number of rows, but even on the larger side I don't see it taking up more than a couple gigabytes.

Note: each time you want to shuffle the indexes you need to drop the index on the shuffle_index column so you don't get duplicate key warnings in the middle of the operation. re-add the index afterwards.

Comment: This looks promising. Unfortunately the primary key is what you see in the 'gopair" column. However, they are simply the set of all possible pairs that can be formed by the elements of a list, so I should be able to generate them easily enough. Hmm... I'll play around with your ideas and report back.

Comment: @terdon each `gopair` is 12 chars, so `60164966*12/1024/1024 = 688.5 MB` for one full listing, assuming that they're stored as single-byte ASCII encoded. Doable.